# Jem's Free PHP Mail Form (Syntax Error)

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am trying to use This PHP Mail form,

http://jemsmailform.com/

and I keep getting syntax errors on 2 different lines. 
Line 70, and 72.

This is what is on those lines.

```
if (isset($requiredFields['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) !preg_match("/^[a-  zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name'])))
    $error_msg .= "The name field must not contain special characters.\r\n";

if (isset($requiredFields['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'] && !preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email'])))
    $error_msg .= "That is not a valid e-mail address.\r\n";
```

Checking this file against a PHP syntax checker here.

http://www.meandeviation.com/tutorials/learnphp/php-syntax-check/v5-3/syntax-check.php

first it said: unexpected '!'

Then I removed the '!' and rechecked, it showed "unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ')'"

So I am a little lost, Not quite sure how I can configure this correctly. I dont really mind if the Name Checker doesn't work, but its the Email validator that I care about. Because you could write: "Email: Gorilla" or something and it would send to my email. So to prevent random spam and useless contact information, I would prefer the email to pass validation.

I am a bit new to PHP, so I am not quite sure where I should go from here, Any thoughts anyone? 
Id appreciate the help.

Take care folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed another `&&` in the first line and on the second if, you missed to close the ) after your empty:

```
if (isset($requiredFields['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !preg_match("/^[a-  zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name'])))
    $error_msg .= "The name field must not contain special characters.\r\n";

if (isset($requiredFields['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email'])))
    $error_msg .= "That is not a valid e-mail address.\r\n";
```

Comment: That being said though, Is there something I can add to make sure the Email is a valid email? that worked and all, but it only makes sure there isnt any invalid characters, meaning I can still send myself an email by using "gorilla" as my email. without a @ and DOT com.

Comment: TAke a look at here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html